# MSCharts & .NET 3.5 SP1

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, mschart

i just download MSCharts, it says i need .NET 3.5 SP1 installed. i already have .net 3.5, whats the deal with sp1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting MSDN:

The .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 (SP1) delivers:

- Performance increases between 20-45%
  for WPF-based applications – without
  having to change any code
- WCF improvements that give developers
  more control over the way they access
  data and services Streamlined
  installation experience for client
  applications
- Improvements in the area of data
  platform, such as the ADO.NET Entity
  Framework, ADO.NET Data Services and
  support for SQL Server 2008’s new
  features

The download can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263.aspx